# Finalize для структуры что бы освободить память

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Мне необходимо резервировать неуправляемую память для полей структуры, я это буду делать при помощи конструктора и метода `Add`. Т.к. структуры не могут иметь деструкторов, я подумал объявить метод `void Finalize() {...}`.

Можно ли так делать? Т.к. `IntelliSense` выдает мне предупреждение о том что это может помешать вызову деструктора.

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Я бы от греха подальше выбрал другое название для метода.

Comment: А он не будет автоматом вызван как деструктор? Еще немного ошибся с описанием, для освобождения памяти в структуре.

Comment: Я очень могу ошибаться, голова другим перегружена, но, если я верно помню, у структур финализатора просто быть не может, а значит и вызываться он не должен.